# what's the meaning of "Per capita basis"?

Tags: meaning

So yesterday Donald Trump said in a press conference that "areas of our country that have been hotspots have done much more testing on a per capita basis than South Korea."
I know that *Per Capita* means per person but what I don't understand is what's the meaning, when it's followed by *basis* like this statement here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare on a "per capita" basis, means to use "per capita" figures for your comparison. You can similarly say

> I will compare the drinks on a "sugar content" basis

This means I will use the sugar content figures to compare the drinks.

The claim is that for "Hotspots" like New York, the (number of tests in New York) ÷ (number of people in New York) is greater than (the number of tests in South Korea) ÷ (The number of people in South Korea).  I've no idea if that claim is true.

This compares New York with Korea on a "per capita" basis.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent explanation!